How to manage Generic Template class inheriting from another Generic class in Python
I'm trying to make a generic Pydantic Schema/SQlAlchemy Model repository using template/Generic Classes but with two stage of inheritance
First stage is to have a GenericSchemaRepository with Generic Pydantic Schema
This GenericSchemaRepository  could by used with SqlAlchemy Model repository but with other type "non sql" repository (CSV, XML, ...)
So I want a second stage class that inherits from GenericSchemaRepository[Schema] and add explicit SqlAlchemy Model to finally have a Repository with Schema and Model that have Generic Templated types
I hope I'm quite clear in my explanations
I don't manage to it. I have an error
TypeError: Some type variables (~SCHEMA) are not listed in Generic[~MODEL]
I Think it is a problem of Syntax as I'm not really familiar with Generic/TypeVar syntax
Thank you in advance for your response and your time

from typing import TypeVar,Type,Generic, Any, Optional,List
from abc import ABC,abstractmethod
from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlalchemy import select
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import ScalarSelect, and_, or_
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
Base= declarative_base()

SCHEMA= TypeVar("SCHEMA", bound=BaseModel)
MODEL= TypeVar("MODEL", bound=Any)

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = 'sqlite:///./database.db'
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                            autoflush=False,
                            bind=engine)

class GenericRepository(Generic[SCHEMA],ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get_by_id(self, id: int) -> Optional[SCHEMA]:
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abstractmethod
    def list(self, **filters) -> List[SCHEMA]:
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abstractmethod
    def add(self, record: SCHEMA) -> SCHEMA:
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abstractmethod
    def update(self, record: SCHEMA) -> SCHEMA:
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abstractmethod
    def delete(self, id: int) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError()
    
class GenericSqlRepository(GenericRepository[SCHEMA], Generic[MODEL], ABC):

    def __init__(self, session: Session, model_cls=Type[MODEL]) -> None:
        self._session = session
        self._model_cls = model_cls

    def _construct_get_stmt(self, id: int) -> ScalarSelect:
        stmt = select(self._model_cls).where(self._model_cls.id == id)
        return stmt

    def get_by_id(self, id: int) -> Optional[SCHEMA]:
        stmt = self._construct_get_stmt(id)
        # mapper MODEL->SCHEMA missing for record (I know)
        return self._session.exec(stmt).first()

    def _construct_list_stmt(self, **filters) -> ScalarSelect:
        stmt = select(self._model_cls)
        where_clauses = []
        for c, v in filters.items():
            if not hasattr(self._model_cls, c):
                raise ValueError(f"Invalid column name {c}")
            where_clauses.append(getattr(self._model_cls, c) == v)

        if len(where_clauses) == 1:
            stmt = stmt.where(where_clauses[0])
        elif len(where_clauses) > 1:
            stmt = stmt.where(and_(*where_clauses))
        return stmt

    def list(self, **filters) -> List[SCHEMA]:
        stmt = self._construct_list_stmt(**filters)
        # mapper MODEL->SCHEMA missing for record (I know)
        return self._session.exec(stmt).all()

    def add(self, record: SCHEMA) -> SCHEMA:
        # mapper SCHEMA->MODEL missing for record (I know)
        self._session.add(record)
        self._session.flush()
        self._session.refresh(record)
        return record

    def update(self, record: SCHEMA) -> SCHEMA:
        # mapper SCHEMA->MODEL missing for record (I know)
        self._session.add(record)
        self._session.flush()
        self._session.refresh(record)
        return record

    def delete(self, id: int) -> None:
        record = self.get_by_id(id)
        if record is not None:
            self._session.delete(record)
            self._session.flush()

class MySchema(BaseModel):
    pass

class MyModel(Base):
    __tablename__="mytable"
    id : Mapped[int] = mapped_column('id', primary_key=True, index=True)

class MyRepository(GenericSqlRepository[MySchema,MyModel]):
    pass

myrepo = MyRepository(SessionLocal)


class GenericSqlRepository(GenericRepository, Generic[SCHEMA, MODEL], ABC): what about that or class GenericSqlRepository(GenericRepository[SCHEMA], Generic[SCHEMA, MODEL], ABC):? I am not sure if it does what you expect if it works

This is  working exactly as I expect
Great Thanks !
Finally it is logical, I was disturbed by Python Way , I'm coming from C++ but finally it is equivalent

feel free to self answer @hervé-le-bars

SqlHere you'll find what I have finally used. This implements the RepositoryPattern base en GenericRpository, base of any kind of repository then GenericSqlRepository, but could be GenericCsvRepository in case embbeded demo files...
Then MyOwnRespositoryBase that should be the base of all kind of repository to access MyOwn Models and overall MyOwnSchema objects. This class allow to add attributes and methods specificly linked to MyOwnModel/Schema/Repo
Then MyOwnSqlRepository that is the bastract instanciation of MyOwnRespositoryBase for Sql Respository, but it could be a MyOwnCsvRepository if the persistence is on Csv or others things a soon as it is based on MyOwnRepositoryBase
GenericSqlRepository ask for a session as constructor arguments in order to be able to implement UnitOfWork pattern design that allow to share and manage a session accross several repositories
from typing import TypeVar,Type,Generic, Any, Optional,List
from abc import ABC,abstractmethod
from pydantic import BaseModel
from sqlalchemy import select
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import ScalarSelect, and_, or_
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
Base= declarative_base()

SCHEMA= TypeVar("SCHEMA", bound=BaseModel)
MODEL= TypeVar("MODEL", bound=Any)

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = 'sqlite:///./database.db'
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL)

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                            autoflush=False,
                            bind=engine)

class GenericRepository(Generic[SCHEMA],ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get_by_id(self, id: int) -> Optional[SCHEMA]:
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abstractmethod
    def list(self, **filters) -> List[SCHEMA]:
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abstractmethod
    def add(self, record: SCHEMA) -> SCHEMA:
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abstractmethod
    def update(self, record: SCHEMA) -> SCHEMA:
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @abstractmethod
    def delete(self, id: int) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError()
    
class GenericSqlRepository(GenericRepository[SCHEMA], Generic[SCHEMA,MODEL], ABC):

    def __init__(self, session: Session, model_cls=Type[MODEL]) -> None:
        self._session = session
        self._model_cls = model_cls

    def _construct_get_stmt(self, id: int) -> ScalarSelect:
        stmt = select(self._model_cls).where(self._model_cls.id == id)
        return stmt

    def get_by_id(self, id: int) -> Optional[SCHEMA]:
        stmt = self._construct_get_stmt(id)
        # mapper MODEL->SCHEMA missing for record (I know)
        return self._session.exec(stmt).first()

    def _construct_list_stmt(self, **filters) -> ScalarSelect:
        stmt = select(self._model_cls)
        where_clauses = []
        for c, v in filters.items():
            if not hasattr(self._model_cls, c):
                raise ValueError(f"Invalid column name {c}")
            where_clauses.append(getattr(self._model_cls, c) == v)

        if len(where_clauses) == 1:
            stmt = stmt.where(where_clauses[0])
        elif len(where_clauses) > 1:
            stmt = stmt.where(and_(*where_clauses))
        return stmt

    def list(self, **filters) -> List[SCHEMA]:
        stmt = self._construct_list_stmt(**filters)
        # mapper MODEL->SCHEMA missing for record (I know)
        return self._session.exec(stmt).all()

    def add(self, record: SCHEMA) -> SCHEMA:
        # mapper SCHEMA->MODEL missing for record (I know)
        self._session.add(record)
        self._session.flush()
        self._session.refresh(record)
        return record

    def update(self, record: SCHEMA) -> SCHEMA:
        # mapper SCHEMA->MODEL missing for record (I know)
        self._session.add(record)
        self._session.flush()
        self._session.refresh(record)
        return record

    def delete(self, id: int) -> None:
        record = self.get_by_id(id)
        if record is not None:
            self._session.delete(record)
            self._session.flush()

class MyOwnSchema(BaseModel):
    pass

class MyOwnModel(Base):
    __tablename__="mytable"
    id : Mapped[int] = mapped_column('id', primary_key=True, index=True)

class MyOwnRepositoryBase(GenericSqlRepository[MySchema, ABC):
    // Add methods specific to MyRepository
    @abstractmethod
    def specificMethodOfMyOwnRepository(self):
        pass

class MyOwnSqlRepository(GenericSqlRepository[MySchema,MyModel],MyOwnRepositoryBase):
    // Instanciation of MyRepositoryBase
    @abstractmethod
    def specificMethodOfMyOwnRepository(self):
        // [Code Here]
        pass


myrepo = MyOwnSqlRepository(SessionLocal)

